# Get a unique identifier of an object

Tags: javascript

So i'm trying to set up a list of objects which contain nodes of pathways. The pathways can be connected to other pathways.

I'm there for trying to link them up with some ID system so i know which objects connect to which objects for path finding related stuff later on.

For example purposes this is the idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
var object = {}; //hypothetical id of 1
    object.connectsTo = [2];

var object2 = {}// hypothetical id of 2
    object2.connectsTo = [1];
```

That way I can call the object by id at a later period when needs be. If this is not an option in javascript - what would be the best solution ?

Comment: Can you give an example of how that works if they can be connected to multiple other objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below, the constructor has access to two private variables: `counter` and `db`. The variable `counter` is used to create an automatically incrementing id and the `db` is used to store references to the generated objects for retrieval afterward.

**`Node` class**

```
var Node = (function() {

    var counter = 0;
    var db = {};

    // the Node constructor
    var _Node = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = counter++; // use the next available id
        db[this.id] = this; // store a reference to the node for retrieval
        this.connections = {}; // initialize the hashmap of connecting nodes
    };

    // looking up nodes by id
    _Node.getNodeById = function(id) {
        return db[id];
    };

    // some utility methods
    // what exactly you want to do with this?
    // not sure what methods you'd need

    _Node.prototype.connectTo = function(node) {
        this.connections[node.id] = true;
    };

    _Node.prototype.disconnectFrom = function(node) {
        delete this.connections[node.id];
    };

    _Node.prototype.isConnectedTo = function(node) {
        return !!this.connections[node.id];
    };

    _Node.prototype.getConnectingNodes = function () {
        var connectingNodes = [];
        var keys = Object.keys(this.connections);
        for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            connectingNodes.push(db[this.connections[keys[i]]]);
        }
        return connectingNodes;
    };

    _Node.prototype.distanceTo = function(node) {
        return Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow(node.y - this.y, 2) + 
            Math.pow(node.x - this.x, 2)
        );
    };

    _Node.prototype.findShortestPathTo = function(node) {
        // path finding logic goes here
    };

    return _Node;

}());
```

**Example Usage**

```
var pointA = new Node(0, 0);
var pointB = new Node(0, 4);
var pointC = new Node(0, 5);
var pointD = new Node(4, 5);
var pointE = new Node(4, 4);
var pointF = new Node(4, 2);

var path = pointA.findShortestPathTo(pointF);
```

Comment: I'm just trying it out on JSfiddle, one thing im not sure of is how i know which object is which so i can connect them together if that makes sense?

Comment: @Dave Can you give some more pseudocode about how you're going to use this? I don't quite understand how you want it to work.

Comment: So each node will have an x,y on a map, and some other random bits of properties to them, and then an array of other nodes that it connects to so the path finder can find a path to destination through these nodes..

Comment: Just so I understand further... Why do you need both the (x,y) coordinates and the connections? Are you familiar with [graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29)?

Comment: Umm well how would i assign x,y position and what its connected to if it connects to multiple (such as that graph inage on wikipedia)

Comment: @Dave I think I understand now. I added some more code above - is that the sort of thing you want to do?

Comment: How do you assign x,y to the system or connect them together so you know which nodes are connected to which node ?

Comment: In the code above, the `Node` constructor takes an (`x`, `y`) argument and there is a `connectTo(node)` method for specifying that one node connects to another. If that is not clear, perhaps you could share some of the game code so I can better understand how it's going to be used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69011/discussion-between-amadeusdrzaius-and-dave).

Answer (score 0):

```
function node(nodeId, connectsTo) {
    this.nodeId = nodeId; // Type int
    this.connectsTo = connectsTo; // connectsTo should be an Array()
}

var node1 = new node(1, [0, 3, 4]);
```

Comment: The problem with that is I have to set the id...rather than it being automated =/

Comment: And you can do that still by passing in a node id to the first parameter of your new node.  For example, `var node2 = new node(13542, [0, 3, 4]);`

Comment: So how would i for example look for node id 4, to check for its properties in your above example? Also that ^ still involves setting a number when creating the node, no guarantee the number doesn't already exist.

Comment: So if say i have 10,000 nodes i'd have to have 10,000 variables to setup ? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: Well you can dynamically create these nodes.  Ideally, you should be using a NoSQL DB for this kind of thing so it scales properly and adds query capabilities.  Then attach a ORM to the data and now you have something scalable...

Comment: Hmm this seems limiting in options - i would of thought JS had a better method than this.

Comment: You should be using a database honestly, JavaScript isn't suppose to be storing this kind of thing.  Try NoSQL or SQL DB's.

Comment: Is that the name of the library noSQL or just the name of a type of db library for JS?

Comment: Check out [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org) and this article [NoSQL Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)